# Rust wasm: missing export function that is defined in a external crate

Tags: rust, webassembly

I have crate A that defines the required export functions for wasm for re-use. When I try to use this crate in a different lib B, functions from A are missing in the final WASM while functions from B are present.

How can I make sure to export the functions from A as well?

update: I was not importing lib_A into lib_b. Adding that solved the issue.

Comment: I am not sure how wasm works, but if it is compiled from lib B, i think you need to make lib A functions accessible in lib B as well, that is some `pub use lib_A::*`